# How can I call a method daily at particular time using a timer in an Azure WebJob?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Do I need to call `Run()` inside `Main()` method? So it will be call on daily basis at mentioned time in code.

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


    static void Main()
    {
        var host = new JobHost();
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously

        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    // This method will be called on weekly basis
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger(typeof(MyDailySchedule))] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
    {

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        try
        {
            MainA.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
    static async Task MainA()
    {

        WebJob1 Service = new WebJob1();
        await Service.DeletData();

    }
}  

public class MyDailySchedule : DailySchedule
{
    public MyDailySchedule() :
        //Schedule
base("2:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00")

    { }
}
```

Comment: I found this video on scheduled webjobs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-webjobs-schedule-and-dashboard/ Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Yes it is very helpful video but i want to schedule job auto because i need to deploy same job on so many environments. Thanks for your help:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the WebJobs SDK to achieve this. Instead:

- Write a simple Console app that directly does what you need to when it's launched (i.e. don't use any JobHost).
- Deploy it as a Scheduled WebJob using cron expressions (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs) for details).

Comment: Is deploying a Scheduled WebJob similar to deploying a Continuous Webjob with a TimerTrigger (from the Webjobs Extension)?

Comment: It achieves the same thing but in different ways. e.g. a scheduled WebJob is not tied to .NET at all. It can be a batch file or PHP script.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please help me to schedule a WebJob that could be run on week day like sunday at 9:00 AM in file webjob-publish-actions.json "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Week",
  "interval": 9

Comment: @RajeshVerma sure, what's the link to your question?